# how to hide gridview before search?

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

```
<?php Pjax::begin(); ?>    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

            'pk_int_payroll_id',
            [
                'attribute' =>  'fk_int_emp_id',
                'value'     =>  'fkIntEmp.vchr_name',
                'filter' => Html::activeDropDownList($searchModel, 'fk_int_emp_id', ArrayHelper::map(TblPayroll::find()->asArray()->all(), 'fk_int_emp_id', 'fk_int_emp_id'),['class'=>'kartik\grid\ActionColumn','prompt' => 'Select name'])
            ],           
            'vchr_worked_hours',
            'vchr_actual_hours',
            [   
                'attribute' =>   'fk_int_payroll_month',
                'value'     =>   'fkIntPayrollMonth.vchr_month'   
            ],
            [   
                'attribute' =>   'fk_int_payroll_year',
                'value'     =>   'fkIntPayrollYear.year'   
            ],



            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); ?>
<?php Pjax::end(); ?> </div>
```

this is my gridview with search.  i want to search and result should show in 
gridView. it working correctly, but before search the gridview show all the data,## how to hide gridview before search??? is it possible

Comment: try this in your controller send $dataProvider as empty it will not populate your data grid value, but make sure this will work if your search is not lookinkg for the data avaible in GridView

Comment: provide the details $dataProvider is ArrayDataProvider or ActiveDataProvider, How your search is working ? are you queryinng for each search or you are using with your dataProvider data

Comment: search is working by using dataProvider

Comment: @santosh i need to search from gridview, after search gridview must show thats what i mean

Comment: create a flag to check if your query fetches data and use that condition to display your gridview in an if condition